# How do I keep the current devise session from being destroyed automatically when navigating from page to page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've looked through the posts about devise's current_user, but none of them solve my problem.  I can access current_user from my rails 3 views (erb files), but can not access it in the controller.

```
<%= current_user.name %>
```

works in the erb.

```
@user = current_user
```

does not work in the controller.  What am I missing?

---------edited------

I am getting nil as value.  It turns out I am able to use

```
 @user = current_user
```

in my index controller, but some how once it goes to a different action (like create) the session is destroyed.

So the real question now is:

How do I keep the current user signed in when going from page to page?

Comment: What do you mean "cannot access"? Do you get an error?  Or is `current_user` nil?

Comment: current_user is nil.  the session is getting destroyed when I go from page to page.  I don't know if its my config somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out what the problem was:  needed to get a fixed rails.js file from

https://github.com/fermion/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js

Many thanks to @Patrick Connor link to his answer

[Devise session immediately expiring on .js call [AJAX]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049672/devise-session-immediately-expiring-on-js-call-ajax)