# Keep User Signed in with Devise

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm manually signing in my users ( a la: sign_in(user) ) because they are being authenticated via a 3rd party API (using OmniAuth).

However, doing this, my user only stays logged in for like 30 seconds (verifying with user_signed_in?(user) -- current_user still holds the signed in user ).

Is there something I need to do to keep user_signed_in?() from returning false soon after signing in the user?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333970/how-do-i-keep-the-current-devise-session-from-being-destroyed-automatically-when)

For whatever reason, the default rails.js killed the session whenever a .js call was made.  The solution is to update rails.js (from [here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Devise::Models::Timeoutable](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Timeoutable) documentation.