# How do you pass devise authentication details to a rails controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, controller, devise

I have a controller action that is expected to be called by jquery. Here's the call:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/comments.json",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            commentable_id: $("#addCommentForm").attr("data-site-update-id"),
            commentable_type: 'SiteUpdate',
            content: $("#addCommentForm textarea#content").val()
        },
        success: function(comment) {

        }
    });
```

It works just fine, but for some reason, "current_user" is nil inside of the controller. If I force authenticate_user! as a filter, rails returns an HTTP Unauthorized.

How can I pass the authentication details so that this controller action works with devise? Even better, is there a way I can make this transparent? I don't want to pass the authentication details over and over for each ajax request...

In Java, once a user is logged in... they are logged in. You don't have pass anything from url to url anymore - it's in a session somewhere and it's all occuring transparently. Is there a way I can do this with rails? I don't want to focus on these details.

Thanks

**EDIT:** The solution is to add the following to your javascript somewhere:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise does maintain sessions.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049672/devise-session-immediately-expiring-on-js-call-ajax) may be your problem.

Comment: This totally seems to be the problem... but unfortunately, none of these solutions worked. Could using jquery-rails be the problem? I am totally lost :( It seems a lot of things in rails is really easy, but if you run into problems, it can actually be rather weird and hard to figure out what's going on. At least we know what the problem is - the session is getting dropped just like what happened for that other person.

Comment: ahh, I had to add the token to the xhr request.

Comment: Hey, can you exactly tell me how you fixed this problem? I am having a similar problem. Thanks.