# Devise signs out after AJAX request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm performing some AJAX requests to add or remove some objects. Something like these:

**javascript**

```
jQuery.getJSON("/apps/remove_screenshot/' + screenshot_id, function(result) {
    if (result.status == 'ok') {
        screenshot_container.remove() 
    }
});
```

**controller**

```
class AppsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  check_authorization

  # ...

  def remove_screenshot
    # ...
  end
end
```

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.http_authenticatable = true
# config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true
config.navigational_formats = [:html, :json]
```

The problem is, requests are performed successfully. But when i reload the page which performed requests, i got *access denided* error.

Still, i need to check authentication when performing the `remove_screenshot` action.

How can i workaround this?

Thanks!

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5052453/583263)

Comment: nope. everything is done already; plus, session is not expired immediatly - controller verification passes.

Comment: @KateGregory Oh the irony of that comment... :) also are you certain you have your CSRF security token included in the head tag of your layout file?

Comment: Can you check the server log to find if the csrf token is sent when you do the AJAX request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with this bunch of code (and rewriting all the non-jQuery AJAX requests with the similar code):

```
$(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
            var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            if (token) xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
        }
    });
});
```

Some of my jQuery plugins was sending the AJAX-request without sending CSRF token.

Answer (score 0):

You've most likely messed up something small. You just need to find out what you've done, here's a few places to look;

Make sure your `application.html.erb` has the following;

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

and then;

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

and make sure `application.js` (in your `/app/assets/javascripts` folder) has;

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: nope. Everything you've described was already done. That is the same as two comments under my question =)